# CSS - moving text to the top left of an image

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, text-align

I'm trying to move the text to be in the top left of the image, but I'm not able to do it.

I've tried vertical-aligning it and adding padding, but I'm positive it's a stupid small fix I'm overlooking.

Here is the example on jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/impo/se9tL7ds/

HTML

```
    <div class="test">
    <p>100</p>
    <img alt="test" 
    src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/32/Spr_5b_289.png" 
    class="pkmn"></img>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.test 
{
     position: relative;
}

.test .pkmn
{
    border-radius: 55px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.test p
{
    font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: There is default styling the browser is doing in regards to `margin` and `padding`. Reset those first before you do anything else, imo. But this is why the answer below works, since it's acting as a 'reset'.

Comment: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ by resetting browser default stylesheet you get more consistency in your layout across browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add following CSS

```
.test p{margin-top:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
 .test p
    {
        font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
        font-size: 30px;
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        margin :0px;
    }
```

```css
.test 
{
 position: relative;
}

.test .pkmn
{
    border-radius: 55px;
 border: 3px solid #73AD21;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
}

.test p
{
 font-family: 'Courier New Regular', sans-serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
     margin :0px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="test">
  <p>100</p>
  <img alt="test" src="http://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/3/32/Spr_5b_289.png" class="pkmn"/>
 </div>
```